# Where can I retrieve information after php filename in URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

Given the url, generated by a wordpress theme:

```
<a href="http://localhost/~site/sitename/index.php/subjects/">Subjects</a>
```

Where can I retrieve the information "subjects" (from after index.php/), once the target page loads? So that I can use it in a conditional statement?

Does that make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: You just want to extract the string from the url?

Comment: Hi, Chris. I want to either show or not show a submenu, depending on whether or not the user is currently on the 'subjects' page.

Comment: So I'm wondering if I can retrieve that 'subjects' from somewhere once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to search for the "subjects" page specifically, or if you want to do the same thing on any page that is index.php/your-page/. Either way, you can use regular expressions to find that page name string.

```
$href = "http://localhost/~site/sitename/index.php/subjects/";
$regex = "/(?:index.php\/)([\w-]+)\/$/";

preg_match($regex, $href, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

`$matches` is an array of matched strings. "subjects" should be `$matches[1]` if any match was found.

The key is `([\w-]+)`, which stands for any number of word characters that could be separated by dashes, as in page names like "my-awesome-page" or just "page". You can compare `$matches[1]` to "subjects" or whichever page name you like.

If you only ever want to find the word "subjects" specifically, you can exchange `([\w-]+)` for the literal `(subjects)`.

Note that `preg_match()` actually returns values whether or not there was a match in the first place:

- 1 is for a match
- 0 is for no match
- FALSE is if an error occurred

So if you just use the literal "subjects" in the match, you can just write

```
if (preg_match($regex, $href, $matches))
    // your logic
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I think I'm explaining myself badly. I'm sure I am. The user will select a menu item from a main menu on my site; the url I gave is the page request that Wordpress generates. Once the page has loaded, if she chose the 'subjects' menu item, she should see a separate submenu on the page, otherwise, no submenu should be there. So I'm wondering if '/subjects' is stored somewhere so that I can access it and use it my conditional that shows the menu.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with how WP handles or generates page URLs. My solution is to find "subjects" in the URL once it is available after page load. It looks like this is what you need.

Comment: Guess I got the ol' tunnel vision.

Comment: I didn't need to use regular expressions for what I wanted to do, but anyway you helped me solve my problem, so thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

According the link above, the link is directly accessing d index page in subjects and no information was denoted to retrieve a filename from d subjects. A GET variable can be used along with subjects like subjects?subject=something

Then u can get d information by calling $_GET['subject']

If d information is stored in DB...U can den query with d information in subject to get d data source name and link to your file location to get d actual file but using get make ur data not secured.....

Comment: Cool. Thanks, I'll give that a go.

Comment: I don't think this will work... $_GET is used to get query params, which would be designated after the `?` operator

Comment: Yeah. I'm not really sure what that 'library' string is. I think it might be something to do with Apache? I don't know.